# Expression for FFT of parametric function

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

If a function is defined parametrically $F_{(t)}=(x_{(t)}, y_{(t)})$, is there an expression for the Fourier transform of function $x_{(y)}$ in terms of the FFT of $x_{(t)}$ and $y_{(t)}$ ?

I checked many tables and found nothing, but, I guess, it should be a known simple and common expression.

Comment: Assuming I understand what you mean by the curious notation, the answer is no, in general there's no nice expression for the Fourier transform of a composition.

Comment: I'm curious about what is curious on my notation. Is the one I been taught on my country.

Comment: I'm guessing that when you write $F_{(t)}=(x_{(t)},y_{(t)})$ that means what I'd write as just $F(t)=(x(t),y(t))$.

Comment: @David C. Ullrich how do you avoid confusing $F_{(something)}$ with the product of $F$ and $something$ ?

Comment: Of course you're asking about confusion in the notation $F(something)$. Hopefully it's clear from context. Standard mathematical  notation is ambiguous here - I didn't say your notation was bad, just curious.